# VBA with if case for checkbox in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am having an userform where I have 8 Checkboxes in it.

Each checkbox is assigned to an call function called autofilter.

I would like to have an vba,in such a way that more than one Checkbox is used, then it should Display the result of selected Checkbox.

How can I achieve in VBA. I am struck how i should proceed with this Problem.

Expecting an help from Forum.

This is my autofilter program

```
Sub autofilter()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result")
wslr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set myfilt = ws.Range("A1:AFU" & wslr)
myfilt.autofilter Field:=12, Criteria1:= _
"USA"
End Sub
```

similarly, i have them for other Locations as well till autofilter7.

Right now, i have the code working in such a way that, if check box 1 is true it calls autofilter1.

I would like to have a VBA, in such a way that, when i select 1 or more checkboxes, it should call their autofilter function together. How can i achieve this ?

[![I have userform with Checkboxes designed like this.in the command button i have the following code,

```
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
Call autofilter
End If
```

similarly, I have it same for other checkboxes.
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zz8gG.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zz8gG.png)

Comment: We need your existing code to make any suggestions.

Comment: I have code for my autofilter function. but i dont know how i could do it for this Situation ? can i post an algorithm may be ?

Comment: Sorry @DavidG thats why i posted it without anycode, i am struck hw to do, i have a Basic knowledge and researched in net if i can find some idea, but i dint find any with this Situation or so which could help me

Comment: Post what you got so far. Maybe post a list of your 8 checkboxes and values (in text or image form) and tell what you tried and what isn't working for you.

Comment: ya ok , I will post that  @Julian

Comment: Is this question different to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44823170/6535336)?

Comment: It is the same. I dint get any reply or Response,  so i posted it again

Comment: @YowE3K i have updated the post with my code and image

Comment: @Julian  I have updated the post with what i have worked so far.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to answer without all the exact details, but I think you are looking for something like:
In the command button _Click sub code, you should have this:

**Edited : notice `Dim i as String` at the top.**

```
  Dim formControl As Control
  Dim i As String
  'loop through every control in the userform
  For Each formControl In Me.Controls
        'Test if the control is a checkbox
        If LCase(TypeName(formControl)) = "checkbox" Then
              If formControl.Value = True Then
                    'The below is very crude and you should find a better way of getting parameter from checkbox
                    'The below also assumes you use ONE filterFunction that takes a parameter
                    'You need to get the number from the checkbox, so take the number from the name of the checkbox
                    i = Right(formControl.Name, 1) - 1
                    'myFilterFunction i (Use this only if you have parameterised your function)
                    'change i to empty string if it was 0.
                    i = IIf(i = 0, "", i)
                    'This calls a function represented by the string
                     Application.Run "myFilterFunction" & i
              End If
        End If
  Next formControl
```

At the moment, the away you've describe it, the code should work. Replace the name of the function with the name of your autofilter function....

Comment: the code is functioning good, but the Problem is, i have 8 Checkbox which are linked to 8 autofilter functions. when i click first Checkbox and give ok, it is displaying me the function of second autofilter instead of first.

Comment: having 8 checkboxes and 8 autofilter function, if i click Checkbox 1, 2, 3 , then i should see the result of autofilter, autofilter1, and autofilter2.

Comment: Then you should subtract 1 from the variable i - `i = Right(formControl.Name, 1) - 1`. Also test if i = 0, then if so, don't append anything to "myFilterFunction"

Comment: still is is not working in the way i want . Can i post another question, describing clearly?

Comment: why not edit this post, and explain what's the problem.Also more of your code-behind if necessary

Comment: Editing this post will lead to confusion when others will have a look at it. I will explain each and every Scenario and the code, i have used for it and an example Image. That will help you also to clarify it better,I could see, this Explanation i not enough and it is not getting me the desired result, May be we could save our time, when my explanations are clear.